# Could bulletproof glass stop a sniper?

Tags: realism, the-punisher-tv

In the TV show the "The Punisher" (s01e07) there is a scene where Frank Castle attempts to kill a man standing at a window using a sniper rifle:

To his surprise the glass stops the .338 sniper shot. Based on a quick Google search it would take 3" of polycarbonate to stop that and 1' of tempered glass. The window in question definitely wasn't that thick, so I'm wondering: is there a material of which an inch or less could stop a sniper round or was that complete fiction?

Comment: _"what I assume is, a 50cal sniper shot"_ - [IMFDB](https://www.imfdb.org/wiki/The_Punisher_-_Season_1#Accuracy_International_AWSM-F) says .338 Lapua Magnum.

Comment: The show is set in the MCU, a world of make-believe meta-materials with incredible properties.

Comment: Bullet proof glass is generally a compound material made from multiple layers of different substances laminated together, so it's much stronger than thick sheet of a single Material.

Comment: That is the entire point of bullet-proof glass...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a question better suited in the Physics Stackexchange... physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Valorum Transparent vibranium?

Comment: @enorl76 I asked that on meta and was told that here was the best place to ask my question.

Comment: @ethan - It's on-topic and answerable *in the context of the TV show*

Comment: The sniper would have to be sufficiently accelerated or hardened or very pointy to penetrate the glass…

Comment: Well, in the realm of fictional materials, one might speculate that the glass used was a cutting-edge "vibrantyl" composite, boasting an infusion of vibranium nanocrystals, which, of course, grants it the extraordinary ability to withstand almost anything. 

Answer (score 5):

In the real world, no. As you've said, any bulletproof glass strong enough to [resist a sniper's bullet](https://www.silatec-bulletproofglass.com/bulletproof-glass/#bulletproof-glass-for-all-requirements) ("Level 10") would have to be [at least a couple of inches thick](https://m.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=34&v=2E_g4rFn40w&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fdigg.com%2F&embeds_referring_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fdigg.com&source_ve_path=Mjg2NjY&feature=emb_logo) unless the round was fired from especially far away.

That being said, we've seen other instances of *extremely thin bulletproof glass* being used elsewhere in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

This is a world where levitating cars have been a reality since the 1940s and the public have access to  meta-materials that are stronger and lighter than their real-world counterparts.

Comment: And yet real cars can have windows withstanding sniper rounds. It's not so simple to tell how thick glass is - one could have serious trouble telling that windows in such car are so thick.